# Control Dask LocalCluster printing to console

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask

I'm sure there is a simple solution to this, but I've got a python function which prints some values as it runs, however, I also want to run it using dask but I don't want to print the outputs of these workers directly to my console.

Below is a simplistic example of my code:

```
def dask_function(i):
    print('Ignore me!')
    return i**2

cluster = LocalCluster(12, processes=True)
client = Client(cluster)

dask_delays = []
for i in range(10):
    dask_delays.append(dask.delayed(dask_function)(i))

dask_outs = client.compute(dask_delays)
```

When I run this I get 10 "Ignore me!" printed to the console. Is there anyway to prevent prints from dask workers to appear in the console?

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think LocalCluster supports redirecting stdout/stderr. You could launch your workers using `subprocess` or the command line and redirect from there.

Another possibility is using a [worker plugin](https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/plugins.html#distributed.diagnostics.plugin.WorkerPlugin) to reassign sys.stdout (to point to /dev/null, some file, or any file-like object) at setup.